# Batch File conditional statement not working correctly

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

So i am attempting to make a simple script to check if an application is running using a external text file (using 1 and 0 for if running or is not). However i cannot seem to get the statement working correctly..

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /p Running=<IsRunning.txt
IF %Running% EQU 0(GOTO ProgramNotRunning)
IF %Running% EQU 1(GOTO ProgramRunning)


:ProgramNotRunning
echo program starting
echo 0 >IsRunning.txt
echo 1 >IsRunning.txt
GOTO:EOF

:ProgramRunning
echo program already running
GOTO:EOF
```

The issue is no matter what value it is, it always only ever runs the ProgramNotRunning code block and not the other.

Prior to using EQU, i was simply using == to check for equivilance.

Much thanks for any assistance given!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - Missing spaces

```
If %Running% EQU 0 (...
                  ^ This space is needed
```

2 - In batch files lines of code are executed one after the other unless one command changes this behaviour. You can iterate with `for`, jump with `goto`, call subroutines with `call`, leave the batch, the subroutine or the console with `exit`, ... but a label will not break the execution. After your `if %Running% EQU 1 ...` there isn't anything that prevent execution to continue into the code following code it none of the `if` tests find a coincidence. So, if the `set /p` does not retrieve `0` or `1` the code after `:ProgramNotRunning` will be always executed.

3 - Missing/empty file. If `IsRunning.txt` can not be found or it is empty (or at least the first line is empty) or if it does contain an unexpected value, the `if` lines will fail. The code executed is

```
file missing    :   if   EQU 0 (
line/file empty :   if   EQU 0 (
bad data        :   if this is a test EQU 0 (
```

All this cases will cause the line to be considered an error and the execution will be canceled.

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Retrieve running state
    set "Running="
    if exist "IsRunning.txt" ( 
        set /p "Running=" < "IsRunning.txt" 
    )

    IF "%Running%" EQU "0" goto ProgramNotRunning 
    IF "%Running%" EQU "1" goto ProgramRunning 

    rem As there is no valid data, assume the program is not running

:ProgramNotRunning
    echo program starting
    >"IsRunning.txt" (echo 1)
    goto :eof

:ProgramRunning
    echo program already running
    goto :eof
```

Why `>"IsRunning.txt" (echo 1)`? Just to be sure there are no aditional spaces after the `1` that will be included in the output (as happens with your code), retrieved when the line is readed from the file and causing the `if` to fail

```
if "1 " EQU "1" ( ...    This will be evaluated to false
```

And this still leaves cases where the data retrieved can make the code fail. For a `0/1` test, it is easier to not read the file, just test for presence of the file. If the file exist, the program is running, else it is not running.

Comment: thanks for the very descriptive answer, i didnt realize .bat script was white space sensitive ;) and was exactly the problem! Also! very good point about the white spaces behind the text. I didnt notice that before. +1